# upload rdl using batch file

Tags: batch-file, reporting-services, rss, ssrs-2008

i was trying to upload rdl through batch since i was having 50 rdls to upload to the report server. one issue which i facing was am not able to connect to report server through .rss file, it throughs an error like "Could not connect to server: http://localhost/reportserver_vessel/ReportService2005.asmx"

Link for .rss file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx2Wo7aMwL3yeDEwT3RBcTd6cW8/view?usp=sharing

batch file as below:

```
 @echo off
::Script Variables
SET LOGFILE="RS Scripter log.txt"
SET SCRIPTLOCATION=C:\SSRS Scripts\PrefixTrendReports
SET REPORTSERVER=http://localhost/reportserver_vessel
SET RS="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\rs.exe"
SET TIMEOUT=60

::Clear Log file
IF EXIST %logfile% DEL %logfile%

::Write Log Header
ECHO Reporting Services Scripter Load Log >>%LOGFILE%
ECHO. >>%LOGFILE%
ECHO Starting Load at %DATE% %TIME% >>%LOGFILE%
ECHO SCRIPTLOCATION = %SCRIPTLOCATION% >>%LOGFILE%
ECHO REPORTSERVER   = %REPORTSERVER% >>%LOGFILE%
ECHO BACKUPLOCATION = %BACKUPLOCATION% >>%LOGFILE%
ECHO SCRIPTLEVEL    = SQL2005 >>%LOGFILE%
ECHO TIMEOUT        = %TIMEOUT% >>%LOGFILE%
ECHO RS             = %rs% >>%LOGFILE%
ECHO. >>%LOGFILE%

::Run Scripts

%rs% -i "%SCRIPTLOCATION%\TrendReports.rss" -s %REPORTSERVER% -l %TIMEOUT% -v REGIONFOLDER="" -v PARENTFOLDER="CrewingReports" -v RDLNAME="rptPurchaseDetails" -v DATASOURCE="localhost\vessel" >>%LOGFILE% 2>&1
ECHO. >>%LOGFILE%


ECHO. >>%LOGFILE%
ECHO Finished Load at %DATE% %TIME% >>%LOGFILE%
ECHO. >>%LOGFILE%
```

thanks in advance.